# Show Checkboxes based on a Condition in JSX

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, jsx

I am new to JSX and my task for this week is to hide the checkbox whenever a certain condition is true. The conditions are when an account is logged in, the checkboxes shouldn't be visible on that account.

The code below is the code for the checkboxes and its condition:

```
<TableRow>
            {!isOpsAdmin || !isOmiAdmin || !isRider || !isRunner && (
              <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                <Checkbox
                  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                  onChange={() => console.log("checked all")}
                />
              </TableCell>
            )}
```

Right now, the checkboxes are only hidden when I login on the isOpsAdmin account, but whenever I try logging in on the other accounts (isOmiAdmin, isRider, isRunner), the checkboxes would be visible and that is not the expected result. Can anyone help as I'm very new to JSX therefore your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to update the logic condition for showing the checkbox:

```
!(isOpsAdmin || isOmiAdmin || isRider || isRunner) && ...
```

this condition will be false if any of the conditions are true.

you might also want to consider using the html `hidden` attribute like:

```
  <TableCell 
     padding="checkbox"
     hidden={isOpsAdmin || isOmiAdmin || isRider || isRunner}
  >
    <Checkbox
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      onChange={() => console.log("checked all")}
    />
  </TableCell>
```

You can either hide the cells itself, or just use the `hidden` attribute inside the `Checkbox` component if you just want to hide the checkbox

Comment: Hi, I've tried using the hidden attribute, it seems to not work even on the isOpsAdmin account, why is that? :(

Comment: can you share what should be the expected visibility of the checkbox?? per variable

Comment: Per variable, the checkbox should be hidden, that means whenever I login onto isOpsAdmin, the checkbox should be hidden, when I login onto isOmiAdmin, the checkbox should be hidden and the same goes for the other 2, the expected visibility of the checkbox should be hidden in those 4 accounts but it only seems to work when I login onto the isOpsAdmin account.

Comment: if the `hidden` attribute doesn't work for you, then I guess updating your logical condition is enough (the first example). I assumed that you used Material UI that's why I recommended hidden attribute.